# How to configure teamcity to build deployment package of asp.net mvc web project and put it into specified directory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, msbuild, teamcity

I created build step with type "MSBuild", set Target to "Clean;Build;Publish", added command line parameters to /p:Configuration=Release;PublishDir=M:\MyPackage

after running configuration I got "success" status but M:\MyPackage folder is empty.

I need just revive deployment package files in directory on same computer but do not deploy to server or somewhere else

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've solved this problem by creating "Visual Studio" build step and add next build parameters

```
/p:Configuration=QA
/p:DeployOnBuild=true 
/p:PublishDir=M:\MyPackage
```

It still do not copy deployment package to MyPackage folder, but it is available in "obj" directory of project sources and this is enough for me.

Comment: I was able to control where the deployment package was published via the OutDir property - `/p:OutDir=M:\MyPackage`

Comment: According to teamcity warning, it is recommended to define System Property on Build Parameters instead.